# How can I define the custom UIGestureRecognizer in Swift?

Tags: import, uigesturerecognizer, swift

I want to define the custom UIGestureRecognizer in Swift, but I cannot import UIGestureRecognizerSubclass and cannot override the methods of "touchesBegan", "touchesMoved", and so on.

"UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h" is in the UIKit module, but only modules can likely be imported in Swift and header files cannot be imported.

How can I import UIGestureRecognizerSubclass and define the custom UIGestureRecognizer?

---

Edit:

I added the below code in Bridging-Header.h and I successfully compiled my custom gesture recognizer.

```
#import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>
```

But this code may import "UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h" for every swift files in my project, so I am thinking it is not the best way.

Is it right way?
Is there another proper solution?

Comment: Your edited code seems to be the best way to do it right now. I suggest you answer your own question with that (yes, that's allowed), rather than put it as an edit. That would be clearer, and I would have another chance to upvote you. :)

Answer (score 11):

You need to add the import:

```
import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass
```

as in:

```
import UIKit
import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass
```